# How to read excel two dimensional parameter in Gams?

Tags: gams-math

I have a Gams model and I want read sets and parameters from Excel to Gams.As shown below:

[image]

How can I read this parameter in Gams?

Thanks

Comment: tried XLS2GMS mentioned in its documentation?

Comment: If you are on Windows, I would use gdxxrw. Here is an example, which should show you everything you need: https://www.gams.com/latest/datalib_ml/libhtml/datalib_GDXXRWExample13.html

Comment: thanks,It is solved,but I do not know, how can I read parameter from excel such as d(j) for example from C1 : C4 with name of parameter ?

Comment: I wrote this:                                                                                                                                         $ call gdxxrw Output.xlsx par=d rng=sheet1!C1:C4 rdim=1
parameter d(j)
$gdxin Output.gdx
$load d
$gdxin
display d;                                                                                                                  but gives zero in gams

Answer (score 0):

For that table you need 2 indexes (i.e. sets) e.g. set i for the column of a, b and c. And   set j for the row of d, e and f. Try this:

```
parameter d(i,j) "Data with column of a, b and c and row of e, d and f";
$Call GDXXRW.exe i=C:\Input.xlsx par=d rng=Sheet1!C1:F4 Rdim=1 Cdim=1 o=C:\Input.gdx
$GDXIN C:\Input.gdx
$LOAD d
$GDXIN

Display d;
```